# Why is my p value too low with > 1,000,000 obs (p<<0.01)

Tags: p-value, significance, t-test

I know that generally a low P value is good since I want to reject the H0 hypothesis. But my problem is an odd one, and I would appreciate any help or insight you may give me.

I work with huge data sets (n > 1,000,000), each representing data of one year. I am required to analyse the data and find out whether *the mean of the year is* **significantly** *different than the mean of the previous year.* Yet everyone would prefer it to be non-significant instead of significant.

By "**significant**" I mean that I want to be able to tell my boss, "look, these non-significant changes are noise, while these significant changes represent something real to consider."

The problem is that simply comparing the two averages with a t-test always results in a significant difference, even if the difference is very very small (probably due to the huge sample size) and falls within the O.K zone of reality. So basically the way I perceive it, a p value does not function well for my needs.

What do you think I should do?

Comment: Why do you think this belongs on StackOverflow?

Comment: You probably want to do a [two-one-sided test](http://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/~rdecook/stat6220/Class_notes/equivalence_testing.pdf)

Comment: I thinks this belongs on StackOverflow since the theoretical answer would probably involve coding, and people are great at that here. plus, someone else who combines data processing and coding might gain from this problem.

Comment: thanks! I will look it up

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the p value. Even slight effects with this number of observations will be flagged for significance. You have rightfully asserted that the effect size for such a sample is very weak. This basically nullifies whatever argument can be made for using the p value alone for "significance"...while the effect can be determined to not be by chance, its actual usefulness in the real world is likely low given it doesn't produce anything predictable.

For a comprehensive book on this subject, [see the often-cited book by Jacob Cohen on power analysis.](https://www.utstat.toronto.edu/%7Ebrunner/oldclass/378f16/readings/CohenPower.pdf) You can also check out [my recent post on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/591627/is-there-a-case-that-we-practically-need-to-run-regression-on-y-with-x-and-then/591637#591637) regarding two regression models with significant p values for predictors, but with radically different predictive power.